# How to transform pointcloud from sensor frame to global frame

Tags: python, coordinate-transformation, slam, carla

I am using carla simulator. From the simulation, I am logging the pose of the car and the pointcloud from the stereo camera at every 50 ms. I want to make a pointcloud map of the roads I have driven on.

So pose is with respect to global reference frame and the pointcloud is with respect to car reference frame. At any timestep the pose contain 6d information(X,Y,Z,Roll,Pitch,Yaw) and pointcloud contain 2d information ([
[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2]...........[xn,yn,zn]]). Here z values denote height and y values denote depth. (sensor frame)

The position of the sensor with respect to car reference frame is (x=0, y=0, z=2.5). Here z axis is along vertical with positive upwards.y axis is pointing forward(positive). (car frame)

What is going to be the transformation matrix using which the pointcloud data is going to be converted to global frame.

e.g. - I want too make map similar to this [Ouster OS1-64 lidar sensor with SLAM - video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5K4yVP76xQ)